# Either or Validation in Razor MVC3

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate

I have a razor view with a couple of textboxes.

I want want to make it so that you either choose one of the textboxes or 3 of the others and you can't submit unless you enter in text in at least one of those choices...
IE you could enter in a social security number, or you could enter in a persons first, last names and Date Of Birth.  For the last option, you must enter in the first, last name and the DOB.  Is this possible using unobtrusive validation?
The following is my parial

```
<div id="searchByDemographicsDiv"style="float: left;width: 50%; display:inline; ">
            @*@using(Html.BeginForm("SearchByDemographic", "SearchPatients",FormMethod.Post, new{ id = "searchByDemographics"})){*@
            @using (Ajax.BeginForm("SearchByDemographic", "SearchPatients", null, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", LoadingElementId = Url.Content("~/Images/ajax-loader.gif"), OnSuccess = "binddata", OnFailure = "FailAlert" }, new { id = "searchByDemographics" })){ 
          <ul>
                      <li>@Html.Label("SSN", new { @for = "SSN" })  <br />@Html.TextBox("SSN", null, new { id = "SSN", name = "SSN", @class = "SSN" })</li>
          </ul>
          <ul>
          <p>Or</p>
          </ul>
          <ul>
            <li>@Html.Label("FirstName", new { @for = "FirstName" }) <br />@Html.TextBox("FirstName", null, new { id = "FirstName", @class = "demoGrphcs", name = "FirstName" })</li>
            <li>@Html.Label("LastName", new { @for = "LastName" }) <br />@Html.TextBox("LastName", null, new { id = "LastName", @class = "demoGrphcs", name = "LastName" })</li>
            <li>@Html.Label("dateOfBirth", new { @for = "dateOfBirth" }) <br />@Html.TextBox("dateOfBirth", null, new { id = "dateOfBirth", @class = "demoGrphcs", name = "dateOfBirth" })</li>
            <li>@Html.Label("Address1", new { @for = "Address1" }) <br />@Html.TextBox("Address1", null, new { id = "Address1" })</li>
            <li>@Html.Label("Address2", new { @for = "Address2" }) <br />@Html.TextBox("Address2", null, new { id = "Address2" })</li>
            <li>@Html.Label("City", new { @for = "City" }) <br />@Html.TextBox("City", null, new { id = "City" })</li>
            <li>@Html.Label("State", new { @for = "State" }) <br />@Html.TextBox("State", null, new { id = "State" })</li>
            <li>@Html.Label("Country", new { @for = "Country" }) <br />@Html.TextBox("Country", null, new { id = "Country" })</li>
            <li>@Html.Label("PostCode", new { @for = "PostCode" }) <br />@Html.TextBox("PostCode", null, new { id = "PostCode" })</li>
          </ul>  
        <input type="submit" value="Search By Demographics" class="button" id="submitDemo"/>     
            }
</div>
```

I essentially want the user to be able to search by either SSN or the other Demographic info with firstName lastName and DateOfBirth being required fields.  If searching by SSN, I want that to be a required field.  very complicated I know.

**UPDATED**origninal validation on my form elements **UPDATE**

```
$("#searchByDemographics").validate({
    rules: {
        SSN: {
            require_from_group: [1, ".SSN"]
        },
        FirstName: {
            require_from_group: [1, ".demoGrphcs"]
        },
        LastName: {
            require_from_group: [1, ".demoGrphcs"]
        },
        DateOfBirth: {
            require_from_group: [1, ".demoGrphcs"]
        }
    },
    messages : {
        SSN: 'Please Enter either a valid SSN or Demographic Info below',
        FirstName: 'First name is required',
        LastName: 'Last name is required',
        DateOfBirth: 'Date of Birth is required'
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think simple way is pass all these value from model and check it on POST , do validation according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you want to go for unobtrusive validation in this case because the validation is very specific. Unobtrusive validation makes much sense when the validation you are trying to accomplish is kind of reusable but that's not in your case.

I would suggest you to implement `IValidatableObject` in the model for server-side validation and do the client-side validation using plain jquery.

Comment: I would love to do what you recommend.  IE use plain old jquery to perform the validation.  But I have know clue how to do that?  Can I do it for just that field or would I have to break unobtrusive validation for all the fields that I have?  Which I have no problem doing, because I have all the client side validation already written and rearing to go.  I have the jquery implemented but it never actually fires.  I am at a complete loss.  Any help would be great.

Comment: Don't have a model for this part.  I do for other views, but this view isn't strongly typed.

Comment: I don't have a model for these partial views.  They are not strongly type.  One of the reasons why I want to just use jquery... I haven't implemented the jquery yet, but I have for other views.  So I will be doing that as soon as I figure out if there is just a way to implement jquery validation calls.

Comment: @DmainEvent You said *I have the jquery implemented but it never actually fires. I am at a complete loss.* I thought there may be some problem in the code and so asked you to share!

Comment: I should have been slightly more clear.  I have a similar older project that I am trying to upgrade.  The validation is implemented in there.  However, I have tried to implement simple jQuery validation with other views, but that didn't work becuase you need unobtrusive ajax and to put a required anotation over your model and so forth.  My question is really is there a way to just put the jquery validation on the view.  I will place my old validation code in my original post